# Cxf interceptors for http exceptions

Tags: web-services, cxf, jax-ws

We are using jaws:client to consume a web service. We have inFaultInterceptor that captures soap faults for further processing. But this inFaultInterceptor is not being invoked for http errors like 404 or ConnectException. We configured interceptors to jaws:client. Can we write any interceptor that captures these http exceptions? Is there any better way to capture them? All we want is to take the control back when such exception/error occurrs.
Note: we cannot catch them in web service code due to some restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `FaultListener` added to CXF `Bus`. The listener will capture the http exceptions allowing you to execute your code before they are raised to invoking method.

```
ClientProxy.getClient(jaxWSClientProxy).getBus().getProperties().put("org.apache.cxf.logging.FaultListener",new CxfFaultListenerImpl());

public class CxfFaultListenerImpl implements FaultListener{
    public boolean faultOccurred(final Exception exception,final String description,final Message message) {

        //return false to avoid standard CXF logging of exception
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Working for me. One more question. We want to communicate between our listeners interceptors and web service code. We tried with cxf Exchange object. But we could not get the data set by listeners or interceptors in web service code. Any other way to do that?

Comment: I have tested creating a custom exception in `FaultListener` and replacing exchanged `Message` content with  `message.setContent(Exception.class, new Exception("custom error"));` The method invocation will receive your custom exception and  you can catch it with `try-catch`. But I have not managed to include other information. With a JAX-RS client it is possible to replace the full `Response` object, but i do not know how to do it with JAX-WS. I guess it is possible